# Locus of points $P$ on the plane such that $\overline{AP}=\lambda \cdot \overline{BP}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, locus

Given two points on the plane $A$ and $B$ and given $\lambda \in (0,+\infty)$ consider the the locus of all the points $P$ such that $\overline{AP}=\lambda \cdot \overline{BP}$. If you study it with analytic geometry you will end up with the equation of a circle (degenerating to a stright line when $\lambda=1$).

- **Question:** is there a way to see that this locus is a circle only by geometrical arguments?

Comment: [HINT](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT725/Apollonius/Cir.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is the well known *Apollonius  circle* whose locus is obtained by squaring and simplification of the given condition.

The result sought uses methods are of geometry and analytical geometry. Also by considerations of *Cross Ratio = -1* by harmonic division the locus can be defined identifying nearest and farthest points of this locus.